# Magento: Grid inside a tab gives invalid tab data on save

Tags: php, magento

Hello I have a tab widget that extends the customer edit page. In one tab i want to display the products grid

```
            $this->addTab('vendorproducts', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Products'),
                'class'     => 'ajax',
                'url'       => $this->getUrl('namespace/adminhtml_tabs/products', array('_current' => true)),
        ));
```

Then inside that function I load the product grid block as is. But when i load the tab and try to save the customer it adds the error css class to the tab preventing it from saving, i have also tried copying the grid to a new file and loading it from there but it still give me an error, is there a way to avoid magento from appending the error class, or is there something i need to add to the grid block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error it's because the fields created by the _prepareMassaction and exports methods on the product grid, you should create a custom grid of products and don't use this methods.